# Redux Motivation: mutation and asynchronicity with example

Tags: javascript, redux

To understand Redux motivation, I read the offical link https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation and this stackoverflow question [Explain Redux : mutation and asynchronicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739084/explain-redux-mutation-and-asynchronicity) but I am not able to get it as example is missing on both the links. Googling also not presented any page with example of combination of mutation and asynchronicity.

What I want is the real life web application example where combination of mutation and asynchronicity is mess. Every page/blog just starts with manage state easily but they are missing real web app example of mutation and asynchronicity combination explanation(motivation). Can anyone help me by giving good example.

> Motivation is saying: **we're mixing two concepts that are very hard
>   for the human mind to reason about: mutation and asynchronicity. I
>   call them Mentos and Coke. Both can be great in separation, but
>   together they create a mess.**. Can anyone give real example on this?

Comment: There are additional libraries for async, most popular are: [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

Comment: @Arseniy-II: What I want is the example of how it is mess when we mix mutation and asynchronicity.

Comment: What do you mean by "mess"?

Comment: @Arseniy-II : That is what I am asking. Go to this redux page: https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation . 2nd last paragraph saying "we're mixing two concepts that are very hard for the human mind to reason about: mutation and asynchronicity. I call them Mentos and Coke. Both can be great in separation, but together they create a mess". So what it means when saying mess? Any example on it?

Comment: It means that changes in your redux store has to be sync in order to kip order. But when you will add async events such as user interactions and AJAX request you will find out that you need some way of ordering async events to preserve order and structure in your store

Comment: @Ripal: As a general rule, keep mutatable state localized in a single component or function if you use it, async or not. Do not use mutatable global state if you can avoid it at all (and you almost always can).

Comment: I think explanation on why mutation and asynchronicity creates a mess is still missing. Let me know if I am not getting you @Arseniy-II

Comment: how about that: when you use sync state your store events will look like this: A->B->C->D. And if you got error on your D store event you know you should check A,B,C or D actions.
When you have async you might have something like this: A->B or С (for example when you request data A success is B fail is C). B->D and C->D (where D for example display notification). Now You have error on your D. Where was an error? Was it C? Was it B? What if your chain consist of 20 store events?

Comment: @Arseniy-II Okay so let say we have real application with feature sign up, login, list post, list comments of post, submit post, submit comment on post. So how the combination of mutation and asynchronicity will create problem and what kind of problem it will create in app when redux is not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With both async and mutation, you lose your "single source of truth" for managing your state.

Let's say you have a global counter initialized to 0. You also have 2 Button components with async handlers, inc and dec that affect the global counter.

If I click inc, inc, dec; What is the value of counter at any point?

We have no way to know which event(s) already fired b/c they are not guaranteed to come in order. So if I'm looking at the counter value 1, is it b/c of:

resolved: inc

pending: inc, dec

or

resolved: inc, inc, dec

With async functions and mutatable state, you never really know what your state is unless nothing is happening.

Comment: Thank you for such a good example. Based on example, I have 2 doubts. 1. So is redux promote sync with state? 2. Why the redux creater call it Coke and Mentos? I read Coke and Mentos theory but not able to match it with mutatable and async issue in real life application.

Comment: Coke is great thing. Mentos is great thing. When you combine together... just google it.
Redux store is great thing. Async is great thing. When you combine together...

Comment: @Arseniy-II and what about doubt 1. s redux promote sync?

Comment: @RipalTamboli: The original author was using a cultural reference about Coke and Mentos as humor. Basically, if you drop Mentos into Coke, it will become a big bubbling mess. Redux does not force sync on state. Redux acts as the "single source of truth" for the data that you put in it as long as you follow its basic rules, like no side effects in reducers. It's really not more complicated than that.

Comment: If you have complicated data flows, you may want to use a library like redux-saga, but, honestly, build a little playground app first to get comfortable with the whole dispatch -> action -> reducer -> state thing.

Comment: As an aside, the React useReducer hook functions nearly identically to redux, so if you find a good tutorial for that, you can use the same exact ideas in redux.

Comment: So this is actually a very good point you make, adding async removes single source of truth.  I guess at least in the implementations of async that use generators/coroutines, there is the additional state of where in the async process the execution currently is.  So state goes from being just in redux store to redux store + all async method's current states.  Would one way to cleanly resolve this be to loosely mirror the async states in the redux store - as in, have some bit of store state indicating whether any given async op (beholden to the store) is in flight?

Comment: async has nothing to do with the source of truth. whether or not you update the store via a sync or async process, the store itself is supposed to be the source of truth. Redux-saga was used at the time of my original comments and is no longer maintained, so it's not recommended anymore. The same thing can be accomplished with thunks and/or react-query now. Note that there are many other state managers now besides redux as well.